# Unable to set up bond interface from 2 vlans

Tags: networking, linux-networking, vlan, bonding

Can someone help me to set up a bond interface from 2 vlans using teamd daemon.

This is how i'm trying to do:

```
 # ip link add link eth1 name vlan50 type vlan id 50
 # ip link add link eth2 name vlan60 type vlan id 60
```

But, when i'm trying to add port on bond interface, i'm receiving an error:

`# teamdctl team0 port add vlan50`

> vlan50: Adding port (found ifindex "15").
>
> vlan50: Failed to add port (Invalid argument).

```
# teamd --version
teamd 1.27
```

Thank's.

Comment: You generally don't team VLAN interfaces together, but rather team physical ports with identical VLAN memberships and then put VLANs on top. What are you trying to accomplish here?

Comment: Thank's Spooler, i cannot use in this way, because the physical interface are already in the bridge - and i cannot use the same physical interface in the bond, that's why i need to bond vlans on the physical interface.

Comment: Post your configs. You're going about this backwards.

Comment: Spooler, teamd configuration is very simple:

{
        "device":       "team0",
        "runner":       {"name": "activebackup"},
        "link_watch":   {"name": "ethtool", "interval": 10}
}


This is what i have:

2 Firewalls connected on 4 Switches.
On all firewall interfaces i have one vlan for management (10) which is also the default gateway for other devices. This is why i did one bridge and connected all physical interfaces in this bridge. Making a bridge from vlan interfaces - i tried, but then it's not working properly RSTP, that's why i used physical interfaces.

Comment: On 2 interfaces - i have another vlan (20), and on the other 2 interfaces i have another vlan: (50)
Now, what i'm looking for is to create a bond interface on the Firewall (Active-Backup) on VLAN50.

Making the bond interface with Physical Interfaces - i can't - because those 2 interfaces are already in bridge.
So, the only way to do that - is to make bond from VLAN Interfaces.

I tried with standart bonding option from linux - and it's working fine. I just wonder why with teamd i cannot do the same.
Thank You.

Comment: Update your question with this information. What I'm really asking for is the network configuration for the *entire machine*, because you're putting this team in the wrong spot within the overall network stack.